# SQL Server : delete duplicate rows without Unique ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have table and it has these columns:

```
pkID    int 
Title   varchar(255)    
FromEmail   varchar(500)    
ToEmail varchar(500)    
CCEmail varchar(500)    
BCCEmail    varchar(500)    
Subject varchar(500)    
EmailBody   ntext   
EmailFields varchar(5000)
```

and my table has **4 rows** data **same value** as below

```
pkID 44

Title 'Notification'

FromEmail NULL

ToEmail NULL

CCEmail NULL

BCCEmail NULL

Subject 'Send Email for Notification'

EmailBody NULL

EmailFields NULL
```

My table name is `EmailTemplates`

If I try this query:

```
;WITH cte
(
    SELECT
        *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY pkID) RN 
    FROM EmailTemplates
    WHERE pkID = 44
)
DELETE FROM cte 
WHERE RN > 1
```

I get this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

I want to delete pkID **equals to 44** it will delete 4 rows so how can I **delete 3 rows pkID equals 44** ?

Thanks.

Comment: Ouch. Unfortunate name for the column `pkID` - it is anything but. After cleaning the data, suggest redefining the column as a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint (if it should be unique), or otherwise remove the `pk` suffix.

Comment: @StuartLC: yep, a **blatant** violation of the *Principle of Least Surprise* for sure!!

Comment: What sql-server version is it?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.3128.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CTE` with `row_number` to delete the duplicates

```
;with cte as
(
select *,row_number() over(order by pkID) RN 
FROM yourtable
where pkID = 44
)
delete from cte where RN>1
```

Note: In `order by` you can mention the in which `order` you want to delete the `duplicates`

Comment: what does it mean RN here

Comment: `RN` is just a alias name to the row number column i have created

Comment: But you need to use `PARTITION BY pkID ORDER BY pkID` if OP wants to use it for more than a single pkID.

Comment: @TimSchmelter `Partition by` not needed for single `pkID = 44`

Comment: @NoDisplayName please check my question again , if i write your query i get error

Comment: @Soner - Updated missed `AS` keyword

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE and `ROW_NUMBER`. It allows to change it easily to see which rows are deleted (or updated), therefore just change the `DELETE FROM CTE...` to `SELECT * FROM CTE`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT e.*,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pkID ORDER BY pkID)
   FROM dbo.EmailTemplates e
   WHERE pkID = @pkID -- if you want to delete only a specific ID
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

If you remove `WHERE pkID = @pkID` you will delete all duplicates by always keeping one row per `pkID`. So you need to change `ORDER BY pkID` to something different if you want to change the logic to something more meaningful, currently it's arbitrary.

If you want to take multiple columns into account, you just need to change `PARTITION BY pkID` to (f.e.) `PARTITION BY pkID, Title`.